# Using Knockout with Ember instead of handelbars

Tags: knockout.js, ember.js, template-engine

Knockout is a fantastic templating engine however it's not a framework like Angular and Ember, Durandal is making good progress however I'd like to explore all the options. So I have three main questions:

- Is there any current support for alternative templating engines in Ember (real support, not just that it's possible)?
- Has anyone already used Knockout with Ember?
- How would one go about adding support for Knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any current support for alternative templating engines in Ember (real support, not just that it's possible)? Has anyone already used Knockout with Ember?

No. Ember.Handlebars is tightly integrated with Ember specifically with its binding system. It may possible but not advisable.

> How would one go about adding support for Knockout?

The correct way to approach this is to have your desired templating language in this case knockout compile into handlebars templates inside a build process.

This has been done quite well in the [`Emblem`](http://emblemjs.com/) project. `Emblem` is an `HAML` inspired indentation based templating language that compiles into handlebars. It has all the required tooling support like node based command line compiler, grunt tasks, runtime support like coffeescript, etc.

You would have to do a custom build if you need this. Else, Handlebars works quite well within the Ember framework, and has pretty much everything you'll need in a templating language.

Comment: Generating handlebars code is not an option I want to take. It'd also be a project on it's own. Handlebars might have everything one needs but it's far from everything I'd want.

Comment: Maybe a better place to start would be to ask a question(s) specific to the functionality you have in Knockout and how to do implement it inside the Ember/Handlebars ecosystem.

Comment: My personal objection against handlebars is that it makes html a lot harder to read for designers that come afterwards. The HTML5 compliant syntax of knockout just makes every nice to read. Writing good HTML and CSS is already painful enough, so I don't want another layer of erb, jsp, handlebars to pollute the HTML code. (Although I have to admit that handlebars sometimes has nicer idioms to express stuff: having to insert a HTML tag for every text substitution doesn't feel right neither.)